# How to unescape an element and remove the namespace attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this XML:

```xml
<DiaryEvent name="CreateAppointment">
  <appointmentId>e69cbf2e-3de7-e411-9fbf-b161700bfb88</appointmentId>
  <originalStartDateTime>2015/04/20 11:15</originalStartDateTime>
  <originalEndDateTime>2015/04/20 11:30</originalEndDateTime>
  <originalAssignee>DOMAIN\user</originalAssignee>
  <initialData>&lt;Task id="b1520763-1369-482e-9133-1e40e5b476d0" userName="DOMAIN\user" createdAt="2015/04/20 10:10:25" formTypeId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" formTypeName="Client Visit" isScheduled="true" minimumFormVersion="0" xmlns="http://mycompany.com/Schemas/TaskXmlSchema/1.0/"&gt;
  &lt;DataItems&gt;
    &lt;DataItem name="QLCl_Client No" type="int"&gt;123&lt;/DataItem&gt;
  &lt;/DataItems&gt;
&lt;/Task&gt;</initialData>
</DiaryEvent>
```

I need to extract the XML from the `<initialData>` element, unescape it, then remove the namespace attribute.

I have successfully achieved the first part using this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="//initialData" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, I am unable to remove the namespace attribute, `xmlns="http://mycompany.com/Schemas/TaskXmlSchema/1.0/"`, from the output:

```xml
<Task id="b1520763-1369-482e-9133-1e40e5b476d0" userName="DOMIAN\user" 
      createdAt="2015/04/20 10:10:25" 
      formTypeId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
      formTypeName="Client Visit" 
      isScheduled="true" 
      minimumFormVersion="0" 
      xmlns="http://mycompany.com/Schemas/TaskXmlSchema/1.0/">
  <DataItems>
    <DataItem name="QLCl_Client No" type="int">123</DataItem>
  </DataItems>
</Task>
```

I have tried various combinations of this:

```xml
<xsl:template match="@xmlns" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

and

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:t="http://mycompany.com/Schemas/TaskXmlSchema/1.0/" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="t" >
```

with no success.   How can I remove the namespace attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xmlns:` is not an attribute node, it is a namespace node. Therefore, `@xmlns` will never match.

If I understood correctly that having two separate transformations is not a problem for you, follow this standard approach to remove all namespaces present on elements and attributes in the input document.

The stylesheet expects as input the intermediate, unescaped document you were able to produce.

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="comment()|text()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Task id="b1520763-1369-482e-9133-1e40e5b476d0"
      userName="DOMIAN\user"
      createdAt="2015/04/20 10:10:25"
      formTypeId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
      formTypeName="Client Visit"
      isScheduled="true"
      minimumFormVersion="0">
  <DataItems>
      <DataItem name="QLCl_Client No" type="int">123</DataItem>
  </DataItems>
</Task>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is it possible to combine the two?  Sorry, I'm rather new to XSLT.

Comment: @Simon What version of XSLT and processor are you using?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 using .Net 3.5

Comment: @Simon If you can neither use XSLT 2.0 or the EXSLT extension functions, I am inclined to say it cannot be done in the same run. The problem is that in XSLT 1.0,  so-called _result tree fragments_ cannot be manipulated in the same way as node sets.